# sending characters from parent to child process and returning char count to parent in C

Tags: process, pipe, fork, parent

So for an assignment I have for my Computer Systems class, I need to type characters in the command line when the program runs.

These characters (such as `abcd ef`) would be stored in `argv[]`.

The parent sends these characters one at a time through a pipe to the child process which then counts the characters and ignores spaces. After all the characters are sent, the child then returns the number of characters that it counted for the parent to report.

When I try to run the program as it is right now, it tells me the value of `readIn` is 4, the child processed 0 characters and `charCounter` is 2.

I feel like I'm so close but I'm missing something important :/  The char array for `a` and in the parent process was an attempt to hardcode the stuff in to see if it worked but I am still unsuccessful.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
// Characters from command line arguments are sent to child process
// from parent process one at a time through pipe.
//
// Child process counts number of characters sent through pipe.
//
// Child process returns number of characters counted to parent process.
//
// Parent process prints number of characters counted by child process.

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>         // for fork()
#include <sys/types.h>      // for pid_t
#include <sys/wait.h>       // for waitpid()

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t   pid;
    int     status;
    int charCounter = 0;
    int nChar = 0;
    char readbuffer[80];
    char readIn = 'a';

    //char a[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

    pipe(fd);



    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("fork error %d\n", pid);
        return -1;
        }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        // code that runs in the child process

        close(fd[1]);
        while(readIn != 0)
        {
            readIn = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));

            printf("The value of readIn is %d\n", readIn);
            if(readIn != ' ')
            {
                charCounter++;
            }
        }
        close(fd[0]);

        //open(fd[1]);

        //write(fd[1], charCounter, sizeof(charCounter));

        printf("The value of charCounter is %d\n", charCounter);

        return charCounter;
        }
    else 
    {
        // code that runs in the parent process

        close(fd[0]);

        write(fd[1], &argv, sizeof(argv));

        //write(fd[1], &a, sizeof(a));

        close(fd[1]);

        //open(fd[0]);

        //nChar = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));

        nChar = charCounter;

        printf("CS201 - Assignment 3 - Andy Grill\n");

        printf("The child processed %d characters\n\n",  nChar);


        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) > 0)
        {
            if (WIFEXITED(status))
            {
            }   
            else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
            {
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: when posting code on stackoverflow, be sure to indent it by 4 more spaces so it gets displayed properly. See the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: thanks, made that change to the editing for spacing properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing pipes.

A pipe is a unidirectional communication channel. Either you use it to send data from a parent process to a child process, or to send data from a child process to the parent. You can't do both - even if you kept the pipe's read and write channels open on both processes, each process would never know when it was its turn to read from the pipe (e.g. you could end up reading something in the child that was supposed to be read by the parent).

The code to send the characters from parent to child seems mostly correct (more details below), but you need to redesign child to parent communication. Now, you have two options to send the results from child to parent:

- Use another pipe. You set up an additional pipe before forking for child-to-parent communication. This complicates the design and the code, because now you have 4 file descriptors to manage from 2 different pipes, and you need to be careful where you close each file descriptor to make sure processes don't hang. It is also probably a bit overkill because the child is only sending a number to the parent.
- Return the result from the child as the exit value. This is what you're doing right now, and it's a good choice. However, you fail to retrieve that information in the parent: the child's termination status tells you the number of characters processed, you can fetch this value with `waitpid(2)`, which you already do, but then you never look at `status` (which contains the results you're looking for).

Remember that a child process has its own address space. It makes no sense to try to read `charCounter` in the parent because the parent never modified it. The child process gets its own copy of `charCounter`, so any modifications are seen by the child only. Your code seems to assume otherwise.

To make this more obvious, I would suggest moving the declarations of variables to the corresponding process code. Only `fd` and `pid` need to be copied in both processes, the other variables are specific to the task of each process. So you can move the declarations of `status` and `nChar` to the parent process specific code, and you can move `charCounter`, `readbuffer` and `readIn` to the child. This will make it very obvious that the variables are completely independent on each process.

Now, some more specific remarks:

- `pipe(2)` can return an error. You ignore the return value, and you shouldn't. At the very least, you should print an error message and terminate if `pipe(2)` failed for some reason. I also noticed you report errors in `fork(2)` with `printf("fork error %d\n", pid);`. This is not the correct way to do it: `fork(2)` and other syscalls (and library calls) always return `-1` on error and set the `errno` global variable to indicate the cause. So that `printf()` will always print *fork error -1* no matter what the error cause was. It's not helpful. Also, it prints the error message to `stdout`, and for a number of reasons, error messages should be printed to `stderr` instead. So I suggest using `perror(3)` instead, or manually print the error to `stderr` with `fprintf(3)`. `perror(3)` has the added benefit of appending the error message description to the text you feed it, so it's usually a good choice.

Example:

```
if (pipe(fd) < 0) {
    perror("pipe(2) error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Other functions that you use throughout the code may also fail, and again, you are ignoring the (possible) error returns. `close(2)` can fail, as well as `read(2)`. Handle the errors, they are there for a reason.

- The way you use `readIn` is wrong. `readIn` is the result of `read(2)`, which returns the number of characters read (and it should be an `int`). The code uses `readIn` as if it were the next character read. The characters read are stored in `readbuffer`, and `readIn` will tell you how many characters are on that buffer. So you use `readIn` to loop through the buffer contents and count the characters. Something like this:

  ```
  readIn = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
  while (readIn > 0) {
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < readIn; i++) {
          if (readbuffer[i] != ' ') {
              charCounter++;
          }
      }
      readIn = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
  }
  ```

Now, about the parent process:

You are not writing the characters into the pipe. This is meaningless:

```
write(fd[1], &argv, sizeof(argv));
```

`&argv` is of type `char ***`, and `sizeof(argv)` is the same as `sizeof(char **)`, because `argv` is a `char **`. Array dimensions are not kept when passed into a function.

You need to manually loop through `argv` and write each entry into the pipe, like so:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i < argv; i++) {
    size_t to_write = strlen(argv[i]);
    ssize_t written = write(fd[1], argv[i], to_write);
    if (written != to_write) {
        if (written < 0)
            perror("write(2) error");
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Short write detected on argv[%d]: %zd/zd\n", i, written, to_write);
    }
}
```

Note that `argv[0]` is the name of the program, that's why `i` starts at 1. If you want to count `argv[0]` too, just change it to start at 0.

Finally, as I said before, you need to use the termination status fetched by `waitpid(2)` to get the actual count returned by the child. So you can only print the result after `waitpid(2)` returned and after making sure the child terminated gracefully. Also, to fetch the actual exit code you need to use the `WEXITSTATUS` macro (which is only safe to use if `WIFEXITED` returns true).

So here's the full program with all of these issues addressed:

```
// Characters from command line arguments are sent to child process
// from parent process one at a time through pipe.
//
// Child process counts number of characters sent through pipe.
//
// Child process returns number of characters counted to parent process.
//
// Parent process prints number of characters counted by child process.

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>         // for strlen()
#include <unistd.h>         // for fork()
#include <sys/types.h>      // for pid_t
#include <sys/wait.h>       // for waitpid()

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;

    if (pipe(fd) < 0) {
        perror("pipe(2) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork(2) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    if (pid == 0) {

        int readIn;
        int charCounter = 0;
        char readbuffer[80];

        if (close(fd[1]) < 0) {
            perror("close(2) failed on pipe's write channel");
            /* We use abort() here so that the child terminates with SIGABRT
             * and the parent knows that the exit code is not meaningful
             */
            abort();
        }

        readIn = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        while (readIn > 0) {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < readIn; i++) {
                if (readbuffer[i] != ' ') {
                    charCounter++;
                }
            }
            readIn = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        }

        if (readIn < 0) {
            perror("read(2) error");
        }

        printf("The value of charCounter is %d\n", charCounter);

        return charCounter;
        } else {
        int status;

        if (close(fd[0]) < 0) {
            perror("close(2) failed on pipe's read channel");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            size_t to_write = strlen(argv[i]);
            ssize_t written = write(fd[1], argv[i], to_write);
            if (written != to_write) {
                if (written < 0) {
                    perror("write(2) error");
                } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Short write detected on argv[%d]: %zd/%zd\n", i, written, to_write);
                }
            }
        }

        if (close(fd[1]) < 0) {
            perror("close(2) failed on pipe's write channel on parent");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0) {
            perror("waitpid(2) error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            printf("CS201 - Assignment 3 - Andy Grill\n");
            printf("The child processed %d characters\n\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Child terminated abnormally with signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown child termination status\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Some final notes:

- The shell splits arguments by spaces, so if you start the program as `./a.out this is a test`, the code will not see a single space. This is irrelevant, because spaces are supposed to be ignored anyway, but if you want to test that the code really ignores spaces, you need to quote the parameters so that the shell does not process them, as in `./a.out "this is a test" "hello world" "lalala"`.
- Only the rightmost (least significant) 8 bits of a program's exit code are used, so `WEXITSTATUS` will never return more than 255. If the child reads more than 255 characters, the value will wrap around, so you effectively have a character counter modulo 256. If this is a problem, then you need to go with the other approach and set up a 2nd pipe for child-to-parent communication and write the result there (and have the parent read it). You can confirm this on `man 2 waitpid`:

> WEXITSTATUS(status)
>
> returns the exit status of the child. This consists of the least
>   significant 8 bits of the status argument that the child
>   specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument for a return
>   statement in main().  This macro should be employed only if
>   WIFEXITED returned true.

Comment: oh man, thank you so much!  I managed to get through the majority of what you explained here by the time you commented (though that did confirm I was doing the right stuff).  What really helped was the line for size_t to_write = strlen(argv[i]);  That strlen() I hadn't been doing and was stuck only getting 4 characters at a time from an argv.  Thanks so much for your help, it was instrumental in completing my assignment!

Comment: @BlackDahlia1147 Glad I could help. I hope you're having a pleasant learning experience in your class.